# How to monitor both reactions and removal of reactions in the same function using Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I currently have a function which is polling a message for reactions and adding users to a list based on that using **Discord.py**. Here is the code below:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        editMessage = message
        tankBoosters = []
        healBoosters = []
        dpsBooster = []
        boosters = []
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author != self.bot.user:
            return
        if len(message.embeds) > 0:
            for embed in message.embeds:
                if "Boost is Ready" in embed.fields:
                    return
                else:
                    pass
            for x in message.embeds:
                if '<:tank:801416324306829312>' and '<:healer:801416334243921971>' and '<:dps:801416343848615947>' in x.description:
                    await message.add_reaction('<:tank:801416324306829312>')
                    await message.add_reaction('<:healer:801416334243921971>')
                    await message.add_reaction('<:dps:801416343848615947>')
                    embedToEdit = x

        def check(reaction, user):
            return str(reaction.emoji) in ['<:tank:801416324306829312>', '<:healer:801416334243921971>', '<:dps:801416343848615947>'] and user != self.bot.user

        boosters = tankBoosters + healBoosters + dpsBooster
        while len(boosters) != 4:
            if len(boosters) != 4:
                reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
                print(message.reactions)
                if reaction.emoji.name == 'tank' and len(tankBoosters) == 0:
                    tankBoosters.append(user)
                if reaction.emoji.name == 'healer' and len(healBoosters) == 0:
                    healBoosters.append(user)
                if reaction.emoji.name == 'dps' and len(dpsBooster) < 2:
                    dpsBooster.append(user)

            if len(tankBoosters) == 1 and len(healBoosters) == 1 and len(dpsBooster) == 2:
                message = f"<:tank:801416324306829312> {tankBoosters[0].mention} \n <:healer:801416334243921971> {healBoosters[0].mention} \n <:dps:801416343848615947> {dpsBooster[0].mention} \n <:dps:801416343848615947> {dpsBooster[1].mention}"
                embedToEdit.add_field(name="Boost is Ready", value=message, inline=False)
                await editMessage.edit(embed=embed)
```

This is working fine, but what I need to do be able to do is remove users from the respective lists (tank, heal and dps) when a reaction is removed from the message.

I.e. a message is posted and 3 tanks, 2 healers and 6 DPS "sign up" to the message by posting reactions to the message and they are appended to their respective lists. Then 1 tank and 2 DPS "unsign" by removing their reaction to the message. I need to remove those users from the list when they remove their reaction. I have looked into using `message.reactions[0].users()` but according to the VS Code debug terminal, `message.reactions[0].users()` is `<discord.iterators.ReactionIterator object at 0x011B5DF0>`
, which I unfortunately don't know enough about python or discord to understand!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    reaction = str(payload.emoji)
    msg_id = payload.message_id
    user_id = payload.user_id
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    exists = db.exists(msg_id)
```

When someone remove his reaction, you know what reaction, the user ID...

Comment: Thanks, this does look useful but I don't think it's possible to use it nested inside
```@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):```

Unless you reccomend a different approach? Is it difficult to have a store of users who have reacted to a message without having some kind of external list/database? The issue I have then is how to specify which message the bot should be "monitoring"

Comment: You should use a dictionary like: dict_database = {}.  if a reaction has been removed you just write bottom the function: dict_database[str(user_id)] = 'has removed his reaction'

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, or frustratedly searching for answers on how to do this, I ended up changing my approach slightly. Instead of doing all the logic inside the `on_message` function, I removed that and used `on_raw_reaction_add` and `on_raw_reaction_remove` instead, and I am tracking users by storing them in global arrays which are emptied once certain conditions are met.

This does mean that the code can only handle looking at one post at a time, but thats all I need it to do for now :)